# Load After Effects animation in Android with unsupported Lottie features

Tags: android, android-studio, animation, lottie, after-effects

I have made an animation in After Effects which consists in a simple `CC Page Turn` effect. I wanted to load it efficiently in my Android app but when I have tried to export it using LottieFiles, it says that "Effects" and "Expression controls" are not supported for Lottie Android (5.0.0).

Is there any way to surpass this error or any alternative for exporting and using my animation in an Android app?